# Titan graph database timeout error

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

I am running titan graph database server but I am getting time exceeded error when titan server is connecting elastic search

Comment: add your error **log** so that someone can help and see where is the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if java8 is present if not install it.
also follow the below procedure to install the titan db properly
1.  Download zip file from https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads and select Titan 1.0.0 with Hadoop 1 – recommended (signature) for download
2.  Make sure java 8 is present and set the java home path to correct location of java 8 (for titan 1.0.0 )

Note for installing java8 use the below command, in same order

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Path location of java8 is “/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle”

3. Unzip the file
4. Go to the location of file (in terminal)
5. Run Cassandra using command bin/cassandra –f
6. Run the command 
   bin/titan.sh start 
   In a new terminal
7. If forking for Cassandra, Easticsearch and gremlin server is working. Only then the installation is working fine
8. Run the command bin/gremlin.sh

Note to stop titan run the command bin/titan.sh stop

Comment: after following your document, it is working as expected. Thank you